# Document Library Type Checkbox missing on document libraries

Tags: document-library

We a number of sharepoint sites that have document libraries where the Type - Checkbox column is missing.
We are on SharePoint 2010.

ideas?

I am currently thinking that the doc libraries that are missing the checkboxes are older sites/libraries that were created in a prior version (and migrated) where the new doc libraries all have the checkbox column.  This is a theory.

Comment: Are you referring to the Yes/No field type is missing from the create column page? Or are some check boxes missing from new/edit forms? Or are they missing from the views? Is it a standard document library with no customization?

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about the Check Boxes that let you easily select multiple items from a view, then it's View Setting.

To get them back click "Modify View", then scroll down to "Tabular View", and ensure the checkbox labelled "Allow individual item checkboxes" is checked.